# Couldn't add CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a calendar app with CardView but it shows an error. Here is the code in image and also I added library in `build.gradle` for the CardView but it shows an error.

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get as code, [not as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency to your bulid.gradle file (app level bulid.gradle)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```